# Team-mate minimization

Tags: combinatorics, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, operations-research

I have set of participants

$$N = \{1,2,...n \}$$

a set of rounds

$$R=\{1,2,...r\}$$

and a set of teams

$$T=\{1,2,...t\}$$

and need to define a function, $F:(N,R)\to T$ that assigns participants to a team for each round such that the number of instances of team-mates repeating, i.e.,

$$\sum_{r_1,r_2,n_1,n_2}[F(n_1,r_1)=F(n_2,r_1)∧F(n_1,r_2)=F(n_2,r_2)]$$

is minimised. In particular, for a given $N, R, T$ is a solution possible where this sum is zero?

For computational complexity I am trying to solve for $n=22, r=4, t=4.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You need to know that in this community you have to write what you tried to do, your reasonings and your doubts.

Comment: With only four teams, during the second round there must be at least some pairs: with $n = 22$, each team has $5$ or $6$ participants, and in order for there to be no pairs in the second round we must place each person into a different team.  But there's only $4$ teams...

Comment: I think the sigma expression is stated incorrectly. I believe the solution as it's stated is just to set $F(n) = \lceil \frac{n}{t} \rceil$ i.e. distribute everyone evenly among the teams, with some teams possibly having one extra player, and leave the teams the same in each round. I take it though that yo meant you want to minimize the same pair showing up on the same team in multiple rounds. So I'd say the formula to minimize is $\sum_{r_1,r_2,n_1,n_2}[F(n_1,r_1)=F(n_2,r_1) \land F(n_1,r_2)=F(n_2,r_2)]$. Would that be right?

Comment: How unbalanced can the team sizes be? For $n=22$ and $t=4$, do you need all teams to be either 5 or 6? If not, what are the min/max team sizes?

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you for editing.

Comment: @Dear An OK thanks for pointing this out. I have considered that testing all solutions is not feasible given the large number of possibilities. I have also managed to achieve local minima (i.e. swapping any pair doesn't improve) by trial and error.

Comment: @Dan Uznanski that's a good point - feeling stupid for missing that - but still hoping to find optimal solution even if the ideal isn't possible for my n, r, and t

Comment: @ColmBhandal Thank you. Yes, you're right - I'll edit the question

Comment: @prubin Thank you for pointing that out. Yes the number in each team must be $\lfloor \frac{n}{t} \rfloor$ or $\lfloor \frac{n}{t} \rfloor+1$

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be formulated as either a mixed-integer linear program (MILP) or a constraint programming (CP) problem. Theoretically, a good quality solver of either type could solve it, provided that you were able to come up with a good search strategy for the CP solver or a good formulation (and maybe some clever solver parameter choices) for the MILP.

I took a whack at the MILP approach. One major stumbling block is that the problem has a lot of symmetry. The symmetry can be mitigated to some extent, but the combination of that and maybe a somewhat loose formulation (at least the way I did it) make for rather slow solver progress. Assuming I didn't screw anything up (a *very* charitable assumption), it appears that you cannot get by without at least 14 pair repetitions, and should be able to do no worse than 23.

If you are willing to settle for a good solution (not a provably optimal one), a heuristic or metaheuristic might work well for you.